# Without Implement Keyword, Can we use interface?

Tags: java, interface, implements

Can We Use Variable and methods of Interface without using Keyword 'Implements'.

Note:Interface and Classes are in same Package.

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean?

Comment: It would be pretty tough to use the methods of an interface considering they don't have an implementation...

Comment: Well, maybe it's Java 8 already ... you can have static methods there :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- All variables of an interface are `public static final` by default, so you can directly use them
- You can implement an interface by means of anonymous class (without using `implements` keyword)

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     System.out.println(I.s); // accessing Interface I's variable
     I i = new I() {

      @Override
      public int getS() {
          return 10;
      }
     };
     System.out.println(i.getS()); // accessing I's method
  }


  interface I {

     String s = "test";

     int getS();
  }
  ```

Comment: Is implement Keyword is not need to access variables of Interface?

Comment: Not at all.. you can use an `interface I`'s variable `v` by saying `I.v`

Comment: Then What is use of declaring Methods in Interface?

Comment: Interface's methods define contract.. read more about them here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(Java)

Answer (score 3):

An interface is a contract for a class to fulfil.  If no class implements it then you're probably misusing the interface.

As pointed out you have access to static member variables, but I'd still question the need for such a design!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `public static final` variables of the interface as constant definitions in your class without implementing the interface.

Using methods , would be useless without implementing those methods in the subclass , as interface only declares `public` methods which are implicitly *abstract*. What will you do with just the method definition without any implementation ?

Interface are actually contract definitions, any class implementing the interface abides by the contract.

You can *implement* interface without the key word `implements` by creating [anonymous class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). **But again are implementing the interface through that class.**

**P.S:** Please try this to assure yourself that interface can declare methods with abstract keyword , though its redundant.

```
interface A {
    public abstract void method();
}
```

Comment: Interfaces can't defined `abstract` methods, only abstract classes can.

Comment: @cfs No, every interface method is implicitly `abstract`.

Comment: I guess what I mean is you can't use the `abstract` keyword on methods in an interface, at least AFAIK

Comment: @arshajii I didn't know that... Java is a strange beast :)

Comment: Is implement Keyword is not need to access variables of Interface?